# Nash's equilibrium

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm struggling with this question and was hoping someone could help. There are 4 parts which I think lead on from one another.

We have Nash's inequality for $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ of the following form
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_2<C\|f\|_1^\alpha\|f'\|_2^\beta
\end{equation}
(1) What is the only possible pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ for the inequality to be true? And write the two relations that they must satisfy. 
\begin{equation}
\left.\right.
\end{equation}
(2) Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, show that for any $\lambda>0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{|k|\geq\lambda}|\widehat{f}(k)|^2dk\leq \frac{1}{4\pi^2\lambda^2}\|f'\|_2^2.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left.\right.
\end{equation}
(3) Show that for any $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and any $\lambda>0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_2^2\leq 2\lambda\|f\|_1^2+\frac{1}{4\pi^2\lambda^2}\|f'\|_2^2.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left.\right.
\end{equation}
(4) Prove Nash's inequality given at the start for the correct exponents $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For 1), try a scaling argument.  i.e. $g(x) = a f(bx) $ to find the pair $(\alpha, \beta)$. For 2), use Plancherel's Theorem. For 3), use something like
$$ ab \leq \lambda a^2 +  b^2 / \lambda $$
for $\lambda >0, a >0$.  Now use 2) and 3) for 4).

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! Could you perhaps expand on how I would use the scaling argument? Thanks!